# How to get the *total* number of results from a paginated `findBy` in Doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, pagination

I'm trying to see if there is a way to do pagination with Doctrine2 without writing custom DQL. I've found that the [`findBy()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L143) function returns the result set that I want, however I'm missing one piece of information to properly paginate on the UI, namely the *total* number of records that the result *could* have returned.

I'm really hoping that this is possible, since it's a "simple" one liner.

```
    $transactions = \Icarus\Entity\ServicePlan\Transaction::getRepository()->findBy(array('user' => $userId, 'device' => $device), null, $transactionsPerPage, $currentPage);
```

Does anyone know how/if I can get this information from the `findBy()` function?

Comment: Have you tried [Paginator](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)?

Comment: I've looked at it however it requires customer DQL and isn't all that terse. If there's no other simple way to get the total rows, then I'll probably end up using it.

Comment: @meze I've looked into how Paginator works and to be DB agnostic, it performs two queries. I'll try out Paginator and see how well it performs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short anwser, no.  You're essentially running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE user = $userId AND device = "$device" LIMIT $currentPage, $transactionPerPage;
```

By specifying a limit, the query is only going to return the amount of rows from your offset inside that limit. So if `$transactionPerPage = 10`, the total rows returned by that query will be `10`.

Assuming the total count is somewhat static, I would suggest first running a count on the total matching documents on the first page request and caching that result ( or storing in sessions ), so you only need to grab the total count once.

**edit:** Example of count query, using just normal php sessions:

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['transactionCount'] ) ) 
{
    $transactionCount = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \Icarus\Entity\ServicePlan\Transaction WHERE user = ?1 AND device = ?2')
        ->setParameters( array( 1 => $userId, 2 => $device ) )
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
    $_SESSION['transactionCount'] = $transactionCount;
}
```

**edit2:** If you really dont want to use DQL, you can run your `.findBy()` with out the offset and limit, and do a sizeof on the results:

```
$transactions = \Icarus\Entity\ServicePlan\Transaction::getRepository()->findBy(array('user' => $userId, 'device' => $device) );
$totalTransactions = sizeof( $transactions );
```

But the performance on this wont be as good, as you are actually fetching all the objects.

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to stay away from DQL if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this ?

```
$queryBuilder->select('p.id, p.name')
                 ->from('\Api\Project\Entity\Project', 'p')
                 ->where('p.status = :status')
                 ->setParameter('status', 1)
                 ->orderBy('p.createdDate', 'asc')
                 ->setFirstResult($page)
                 ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

Comment: An answer does not normally involve a question.